# What is a concrete example of why one wants to have a *derived category* in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, derived-functors

My question asks for a concrete (and hopefully easy) example, why one wants to *derive* things in algebraic geometry. I heard, that a resolution of an object by free ones behaves much better than the original object but until now these are only meaningless phrases to me. Here is the setting, I would like to understand the term 'derived' in:

Let $X$ be a scheme and $X_Z$ (or $X_{ét}$, if you like) the small Zariski (or the small étale) Grothendieck site on $X$. Consider the abelian category $Shv^{Ab}(X_Z)$ of sheaves of abelian groups on $X_Z$. What is a concrete example why one likes to build complexes $Ch(Shv^{Ab}(X_Z))$ on that category and then the derived category $D(X_Z)$ in the sense of homological algebra (i.e. inverting the quasi-isomorphisms)?

If this setting is not appropriate enough, one can consider the ring object $\mathcal{O}_X$ in $Shv^{Ab}(X_Z)$ and [modules](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module#Rings) over it. This category is again abelian, one forms chain complexes on it and the derived category $D(X_Z,\mathcal{O}_X)$. Why? What is an concrete example for the necessity of this complicated process?

Comment: One takes resolutions all the time to compute cohomology, yet cohomology is not a "complete invariant": the quasi-isomorphism type of the resolution carries more information.

Comment: Yes, that's a point. Thank you for pointing that out! Anyway, I would appreciate a concrete example like something with 'intersection theory' behaving well in the derived setting but nor in the classical one.

Comment: +1 since I also would like to see a concrete example. I think that the formalism of derived categories simplify a lot. For example, the complicated Grothendieck spectral sequence is essentially the trivial equation $R(F \circ G) = R(F) \circ R(G)$ in the derived category, following from the universal property of $R(F)$. I think Zhen has explained this somewhere else nicely.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One motivation is [deformation theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/deformation+theory), see [MO:111084](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111084/why-are-derived-categories-natural-places-to-do-deformation-theory).  Basically, the [cotangent complex](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cotangent+complex) turns out to be the left [derived functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived+functor) of the [Kähler differentials](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kaehler+differentials) functor $\Omega^1$.

In intersection theory, [Serre's intersection formula](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Serre+intersection+formula) is another example, see [MO:12236](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12236/serre-intersection-formula-and-derived-algebraic-geometry).  The Tor's in this formula are simply the [homotopy groups](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+group) of the [derived tensor product](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived+tensor+product), taken in the [derived category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived+category) of [*simplicial* commutative algebras](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+algebra).  Hence the intersection multiplicity is nothing but the length of this derived tensor product, viewed as a [simplicial module](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+module).

Both of these examples also lead quite naturally into the world of [derived algebraic geometry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived+algebraic+geometry) in the sense of Toën–Vezzosi or Lurie.

However, I should mention that more traditionally (i.e. in non-derived geometry),  the [derived category of (quasi-)coherent sheaves](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/triangulated+category+of+sheaves) is not usually used for computing resolutions or such, but rather as a kind of package of classically interesting geometric data about your variety.  In fact, in some cases this triangulated category contains sufficient information to [reconstruct](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Bondal-Orlov+reconstruction+theorem) your original variety up to isomorphism.  For this perspective, see papers of Bondal and Orlov, like [arXiv:math/0206295](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206295).

In fact in [noncommutative algebraic geometry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/noncommutative+algebraic+geometry) or [derived noncommutative algebraic geometry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived+noncommutative+algebraic+geometry), varieties are completely replaced by their [derived categories of (quasi-)coherent sheaves](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/triangulated+category+of+sheaves) or [stable (∞,1)-categorical](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stable+%28infinity%2C1%29-category) enhancements thereof.  Thus a *noncommutative space* in this sense is a kind of [stable $k$-linear (∞,1)-category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2C1%29-category) (often a [DG category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/DG+category)).
A good introduction to this subject is [arXiv:1108.3787](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3787).

Comment: I have never seen an answer with such a great quotient # nlab-links / # lines.